# Function for taking screenshots with different names

Tags: python, screenshot

It always takes the image and replaces it with Picture1, and it just keeps replacing it.

I want it to create new pictures going from Picture1 to Picture2,... each time I press Page Up.

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time

s=0 # this was the mistake thanks L3viathan 
def shoot():
    global s # this also has to be here thanks ggorlen
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save(r'D:\Py\ss\Picture'+str(s)+'.png')
    s=s+1

keyboard.add_hotkey('page up', shoot)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! How about moving `s = s + 1` into the `shoot` function?

Comment: Thank you. When i do that i get this error

UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
and 
handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())

Comment: Add `global s` to the top of the function. Note that this is poor practice; better to use a closure to scope the variable locally but for a little script like this it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Now it says NameError: name 's' is not defined
I put global s right below def shoot(): with 1 tab space

Comment: This should work with those two changes. Can you update the question with your current code?

Comment: Yeah sure man. Also I tried it without function using while and it worked but i kinda need it to be on a keypress.

Comment: Before the function, do `s = 0`, leave the rest as-is. The `global` statement doesn't declare a global variable, it just marks a name as belonging to the global scope within a function.

Comment: Ah yes that worked. Idk why I deleted it in the first place my process of thought was to make it global as the ggorlen said but I totaly forgot that it still has to be given value. Thank you very much!